# Popup not working in browser but works in codepen

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

For some reason, the code works in Codepen but when I start a live server with VScode the popup no longer works. I looked in the console and got an error that said "Uncaught TypeError: ebBtn is null" I'm not sure what to fix. I turned off popup blockers as well and thought that would help but still nothing shows up

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  var ebModal = document.getElementById("mySizeChartModal");
  var ebBtn = document.getElementById("mySizeChart");
  var ebSpan = document.getElementsByClassName("ebcf_close")[0];
  ebBtn.onclick = function() {
    ebModal.style.display = "block";
  };
  ebSpan.onclick = function() {
    ebModal.style.display = "none";
  };
  window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == ebModal) {
      ebModal.style.display = "none";
    }
  };
});
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */

.ebcf_modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}


/* Modal Content */

.ebcf_modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}


/* The Close Button */

.ebcf_close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.ebcf_close:hover,
.ebcf_close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<h2>Popup</h2>
<a href="#" id="mySizeChart">Open Modal</a>
<div id="mySizeChartModal" class="ebcf_modal">
  <div class="ebcf_modal-content">
    <span class="ebcf_close">&times;</span>
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur sit nemo porro, a illum vitae repellendus dicta labore tempora. Eum, maxime illo id totam alias sint voluptatem consectetur fugiat est!</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is working in browser when i test. What error shown in console??

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache? If you changed the id of the element at some point and the browser is caching an older version of the script, it might give you that error `Uncaught TypeError: ebBtn is null`

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to CSS? If not, please remove the tag. Also, share your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Your snippet works fine for me in Chrome (Windows, Latest). FYI, typical popup blocking only impacts `window.open()` and the like, not DOM elements used as a modal.

Comment: I imported the code into vscode.  It worked as expected and regardless of where in the page I placed the script tag.  Please check that the code you've posted here is identical to the code where you see the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the help when I cleared the cache it worked. I didn't realize that because I changed the id of the element it was possible to cache an older version. It works now thank you!